# C#/.NET Exception performance?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, exception

Below you'll see a little benchmark test.
The left button uses a return value and the right one uses try/catch. 
The line

```
if(i < 0) throw new Exception("xxxx");
```

gives me a headache. *i* is never <0 thus the exception is never thrown. But why is DoTry so much slower then Try with return value. The funny thing is, if I omit "xxxx" and write `Exception()`, `DoTry()` is faster then `Do()`. But the branch with throw is never executed, so why does it make a performance difference if a pass a string to Exception or not?

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="ExceptionTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExceptionTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display">
    <Grid>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="102,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="287,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click"/>

  </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;

namespace ExceptionTest {
  public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    long ii = 10000000;

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
      sw.Start();
      for(long i = ii; i > 0; i--) {
        for(int j = 100; j > 0; j--) {
          bool r = Do();
        }
      }
      sw.Stop();
      Title = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
      sw.Start();
      for(long i = ii; i > 0; i--) {
        try {
          for(int j = 100; j > 0; j--) {
            DoTry();
          }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
        }
      }
      sw.Stop();
      Title = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
    }

    void DoTry() {
      int i = 1;
      i++;
      if(i < 0) throw new Exception("xxxx");
    }

    bool Do() {
      int i = 1;
      i++;
      if(i < 0) return false;
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

---

Answer: As stated by Sefe, it looks like the inlining. Adding more code to the dead branch if the Do function caused the Try version to perform better.

Comment: Throwing an exception means *stack trace* which is slow; exceptions are exceptional, they are not supposed to be typical behaviour

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean with "slower"? What is your performance data?

Comment: I'd guess inlining is the difference, but I'd want to see the disassembly of it after jitting to be sure.

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko: The Exception in the example will never be thrown. i will never get below 0. In this case a change of code in a branch that is never executed makes a performance difference.

Comment: @Sefe: By slower I mean that the version with the return value needs 390ms while the Exception version needs 1250ms. And this is all because of the string I pass to the constructor of Exception, which is never called.

Comment: If your data is fullly reproducable, I sincerely doubt it's the exception. My best guess is that with the argument to the exception, your method size becomes larger than 32 IL instructions, which precludes inlining. Extend your then-block in `Do` with more instructions and try again.

Comment: The jitter might also choose to avoid inlining a method which throws because that messes up the stack trace in debugging scenarios.  But if you want to know what the jitter does, look at the generated assembly. Your best bet is to run the release version of the code outside the debugger *past* the first runs of the code,then attach the debugger and look at the jitted code. Remember, the jitter might make different choices if it knows a debugger is attached.

Comment: @EricLippert: "Remember, the jitter might make different choices if it knows a debugger is attached." So, is there no simple way to get the jitted code without incurring in the [observer effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(information_technology))?

Comment: @LucaCremonesi: Well that depends on what you think is "simple". I gave the technique that I use in the previous comment: run the release code so that it jits *before* the debugger is attached, and then attach the debugger and examine the code. To my knowledge no version of the jitter re-jits after a debugger is attached late.

Comment: @EricLippert: Thank you, I had misunderstood the part regarding the jitter knowing when a debugger is attached. I thought it might have re-jitted the code in this case. Now it is clear to me that once the code has been jitted you can attach a debugger without fearing to alter the generated code.

Comment: @LucaCremonesi: Today you can. Tomorrow, who knows? The jitter does not make guarantees about what gets jitted when, and there are other virtual machines that do re-jit code when they believe they can do a better job.